# SqlDataReader for Date data-type into maskedtextbox

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

Hello I have got this `SqlDataReader` which reads date datatype from SQL DB into `maskedTextBox` with mask `MM/DD/YYYY` but when the date is e.g. 05/05/2005 it would be displayed in maskedtextbox like this 55/20/05__ on Windows XP .

Is there solution to prevent this?

On Windows 8 it is read as 5_/5_/2005 which is correct

```
           string query = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE name='" + selectedrow + "' AND year='" + selectedyear+ "'";
            SqlCommand command= new SqlCommand(query, con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader read= command.ExecuteReader();

            if (read.Read())
            {

                object nulldate = (maskedTextBox2.Text = read.IsDBNull(24) ? 
                    string.Empty : read.GetDateTime(24).ToShortDateString()); } con.Close();
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Masked Textbox is only supported on windows xp SP3 (Or SP2 for x64 version) The easiest solution would be to run windows update on your installation of Xp. (PS; your sql cmd string is vulnerable to injection)

Comment: @Amber That is correct, my test machine is SP3 and maskedtextbox displayes correctly but the date when I load it the dates and months are loaded without 0 on the beggining. for example date 12/12/2012 will load correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used the masked text box, but you could possibly use one of the DateTime ToString overrides that provides formatting options.

As referenced here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx, something like this:

```
string formatted = read.IsDBNull(24) ? string.Empty : read.GetDateTime(24).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```